# I need help making a path for JDK 9.0.1 and making cmd run a command called javac HelloApp.java

Tags: javascript, java, path

Right now my path for the JDK 9.0.1 is in the system variables and is called C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin

Below is my path I have for the JDK 9.0.1
[image]

For the second image is the file I have named `HelloApp.java` which I am trying to do in CMD and the coding in it
[image]

Now on the 3rd image this is the response I get from CMD
[image]

Note: I am coding with a book called Java for dummies 8 in one.
Thanks for reading this!

Comment: where is your file `HelloApp.java` located? and where are you trying to execute it

Comment: @Michael javac as a command is found, his file isn't found to compile

Comment: My HelloApp.java is located in a folder called coding stuff on my desktop C:\Users\Ibrahim\Desktop\Coding

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder by doing `cd` where `HelloApp.java` file exits. Then run java commands

Comment: or run `javac C:/my/absolute/path/HelloApp.java`

Comment: @Michael I ran that same thing happened. And what do u mean by go to the folder?

Comment: @PlzhelpMe A command prompt has the concept of a current *working directory*. Your current working directory is `C:\Users\Ibrahim`. You need to either navigate to the correct directory in order for `javac` to know the file is there, or specify the full path to where the file is located.

Comment: Aight so how do I do that?

Comment: @PlzhelpMe `cd C:/the/folder/where/your/file/exists`

Comment: Ohhhh thanks :) Just to make sure I did it correctly so I do javac then C:\Users\Ibrahim\Desktop\Coding\HelloApp.java next to it right?

Comment: Wait so now when I am trying to run the .class file created what do I type in CMD?